# Как передать значение переменной из одной функции в другую? (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

Пример:

```
fun examplefunction() {
    val x = word
}

fun onClick(view: View?) {
    when(view?.id) {
        R.id.mode_selection_info_button -> {
        val y = second " + "$x"
        }
    }
}
```

Было бы логично, во-первых, задать константой, но так не получится: этот условный "x" надо будет в этой функции, и поэтому вне неё его записать невозможно. Второй раз так же его найти, просто в другой функции, тоже нельзя. Нужно именно каким-то образом получить значение x в другой функции. Может быть, с другим именем, но то же значение. Как это сделать?
Kotlin

Answer (score 2):

Обычно что-то такое делают (функции умеют возвращать значения)

```
fun examplefunction(): String {
    val x = word
    return x
}

fun onClick(view: View?) {
    when(view?.id) {
        R.id.mode_selection_info_button -> {
            val x = examplefunction()
            val y = second " + "$x"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще непонятно в чем проблема. Во-первых, все прекрасно задается вне функции:

```
val x = "word"
fun examplefunction() {
    print(x)
}
```

Во-вторых, если в функции нужно какое-то значение, то его можно просто-напросто туда передать.

В-третьих, значение полученое в какой-то функции, можно из нее вернуть.

Comment: А если необходимо вернуть из функции несколько значений?

Comment: @Mikke то можете вернуть несколько значений.